# json.jsonexception because passing wrong path or Value <!DOCTYPE

Tags: android, json

I guess the PHP file I add are wrong , please can you tell me what to add excatly.

my logcat is giving this errors:(my problem is here W/System.err(14380): org.json.JSONException: Value

```
06-27 12:17:48.313: I/System.out(14380): Thread-2581(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
06-27 12:17:48.328: I/System.out(14380): Thread-2581(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
06-27 12:17:48.328: I/System.out(14380): Thread-2581(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
06-27 12:17:49.698: I/System.out(14380): AsyncTask #1 calls detatch()
06-27 12:17:50.808: I/System.out(14380): AsyncTask #1 calls detatch()
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): > <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <head>
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <title>Web hosting, domain names, VPS - 000webhost.com</title>
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <link href="/new_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): </head>
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <script type="text/javascript">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): </script>
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <script type="text/javascript">
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): try {
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-10701068-1");
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): pageTracker._trackPageview();
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): } catch(err) {}</script>
06-27 12:17:50.808: D/Create Prediction Request:(14380): <map name="map1">
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at com.example.zproject.MainActivity$AddNewPrediction.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:150)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at com.example.zproject.MainActivity$AddNewPrediction.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-27 12:17:50.813: W/System.err(14380):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

this is my ip

```
private String URL_NEW_PREDICTION = "http://31.170.160.102/new_predict.php";
```

this is config.php . I am testing the app in a free host ,

```
<?php
 // Database configuration
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'a6901827_moudiz');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
    define('DB_HOST', 'mysql12.000webhost.com');
    define('DB_NAME', 'a6901827_justed');
?>
```

this my new_predict.php code.

```
<?php
include_once './DbConnect.php';
function createNewPrediction() {
         $response = array();
        $goalNum = $_POST["goalNo"];
        $cardNum = $_POST["cardNo"];
        $posDiff = $_POST["posDiff"];
                $db = new DbConnect();
       // mysql query
        $query = "INSERT INTO prediction(goalNum,cardNum,posDiff) VALUES('$goalNum','$cardNum','$posDiff')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($result) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Prediction added successfully!";
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to add prediction!";
        }
       // echo json response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
createNewPrediction();
?>
```

this is dbconnect.php

```
<?php
class DbConnect {  
        private $conn;        
        function __construct() {        
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
        }        
        function __destruct() {        
        $this->close();
        }        
        function connect() {        
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';                  
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());         
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());        
        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;
        }        
         // Close function          
        function close() {
        // close db connection
        mysql_close($this->conn);
        }
}
?>
```

this is my code

```
   protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String goalNo = arg[0];
            String cardNo = arg[1];
            String posDiff = arg[2];

            // Preparing post params
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("goalNo", goalNo));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardNo", cardNo));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("posDiff", posDiff));

            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();

            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_NEW_PREDICTION,
                    ServiceHandler.POST, params);

            Log.d("Create Prediction Request: ", "> " + json);
```

.........

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {

                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to parse an XML as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "`include_once './DbConnect.php';` "  to   `include 'DbConnect.php';`

change and replace to all `php` file try it.

Comment: oh now I have another error .. can you help me with it ?     06-27 14:10:18.492: W/System.err(11048): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "error404.000webhost.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: Now this error give to file not found in 000webhost.com server.

Comment: So that you have to check first all php file are there if yes then check

Comment: yes I changed the url , and somehow worked thanks anyway